# What is the event fired when deselect a TableRow in material-ui

Tags: material-ui

My use case is when a row is selected, a button is highlighted for some action. When the row is deselected, the button need to be disabled. There is already an event onRowSelection, what I need is an event hook when row is de-seleceted.

Or is there any other idea to implement such behavior. Hopefully not watch the entire row state. That would be costly.

[edit]

turns out, onRowSelection suits my need well. When rows are deselected, the onRowSelection call back is also called, and the cb function has an empty array argument.